# Passing data with props defined in grandparent to grandchild

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Parent class:

```
<template>
  <BaseButton icon="activity">Slotted Text</BaseButton>
</template>
```

Child class: BaseButton

```
<template>
  <div>
     {{ icon }} // returns the expected result; prop is coming in.
     <slot>Default Text</slot> 
     <BaseIcon :name="{{icon}}" /> <-- error is here, see below. 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
```

Grandchild:

```
<template>
  <div class="icon-wrapper" v-html="svg"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: String
  }
  // code that uses the name prop
}
</script>
```

The error is:

```
Unexpected token '{' in

    {{icon}}
```

Is there a way to pass the expression into the prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the binding `v-bind:name="icon"` to bind the attribute with the property :

```
  <BaseIcon v-bind:name="icon" />
```

or the shorthand :

```
  <BaseIcon :name="icon" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying. I appreciate your help. In this case, I did try that, and I get the 2nd error stated in the question "Unexpected token"

Comment: please share the whole new tried code with `:`

Comment: Ok, I simplified the question.  I only included the error from when I used v-bind:name

Comment: you should remove `{{}}` and keep it like `:name="icon"`

Comment: That was it. I don't know how I didn't try that originally (guess it is time for bed!), but I am able to pass the data all the way down now.  Thank you!